# Input file not opening File Upload box on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, label, forms

I have a `label` element which, along with its corresponding `input type="file"`, also contains an `img` sandwiched between two `span` elements.

The `input` itself is declared as `display:none`, allowing the `label` to do the job of launching the File Upload box when any element inside it is clicked. This, of course, works swimmingly in every major browser except IE. In IE, clicking anywhere inside the `label` **other** than the `img` will launch the File Upload box, but clicking the `img` will not...

You can see this issue replicated by opening [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de531suo/5/) in IE alongside any other browser.

Strangely, the issue can be isolated down to the presence of the `form`. For some reason when the `form` wrapper is removed the label functions correctly. I obviously can't use this as a solution though. Thoughts?

Comment: As a workaround, you can turn `paperclip` into a span with a background image. This works, see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/de531suo/6/); it's not a solution though, so not posting as an answer.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for that. I can duplicate in my code and it does in fact function properly as a workaround. As you stated though, it is not a solution.

Comment: Well IE is correct to the specification the label is not allowed to contain any element this includes your img tag, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known bug in IE you can see it in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809378/using-images-as-labels-inside-forms-in-internet-explorer-11)

To solve simply add `pointer-events: none;` to the `<img>`

It can cause some browsers to highlight the image when being clicked. To avoid that make the image unselectable.

The full solution is:

```
.selector-for-image {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

See [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agdykyt6/)